# Unable to login to a website using HTTrack

Tags: httrack

I am trying to download the content of a website using HTTrack software.

The website requires login details.

[image]

After selecting the directory to save in, I added the URL. "http://*****/login
I selected capture URL and temporarily added the temporary proxy settings to my LAN settings:

Proxy's address:
fe80::55dd:bbbd:2fd2:c7b9
Proxy's port:
8080

The address did not work. I put it between [] and it worked.

I tried login in with the proxy on but I got no sign that the link was captured into HTTrack and I got the following error: 
" We couldn't sign you in.
An error has occurred. Check your Internet connection and try again."

Continuing with process on HTTrack gives an error:

[image]

I would be grateful if you can assist me. 
Kindly,
Olfa